# Converting year quarter string like 01Q1 to datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I wanted to know how would I convert a string object like `01Q1` (which stands for 2001, Quarter 1) into a datetime object in Python. Thanks!

Comment: What exact date you think 01Q1 should be? 1 Jan 2001 or 31 Mar 2001? Or something else?

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen Yes, something like 2001-03-01. Or do you think 2001-03-31 makes more sense for quarterly data?

Comment: For quarter 1, you'd normally have Jan 1st for quarter start or Mar 31st for quarter end, not Mar 1st?

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with syntax and know what int() function does, then it should be easy to understand the code below

```
import datetime

def str_to_datetime_v1(s):
    year = 2000 + int(s[0:2])
    quarter_months = {"1": 1, "2": 4, "3": 7, "4": 10}
    month = quarter_months[s[3]]
    return datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)

def str_to_datetime_v2(s):
    year = 2000 + int(s[0:2])
    month = int(s[3]) * 3 - 2 
    return datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
```

I made some tests. Functions has almost same speed on my system, but v1 is a few percents faster.

You can move `quarter_months` dict creation outside of function because you don't want it to be recreated on every call. In this case I got 14% speedup.